# Trying to utilize an input.txt file into a output.txt file in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to test my application by printing into an output.txt file. There is an input.txt file that already contains four honor students and at least two with the same GPA of 3.9, and three that are not honors students. The results should be sent to the output.txt file. The output.txt file should contain: 
1) All of the students
2) The best student
3) Number of honors students in the list
4) Honors students
The input.txt file that I created contains the following (in order) last names, first names, id, GPA, and year.

The class TestStudents prints the input.txt file. However, I need it to utilize the input.txt file in order to print the above mentioned output.txt file. Thank you very much.

Student class -

```
public class Student
{
    String lastName, firstName, id;
    double gpa;
    int year;

    public Student (String lastName, String firstName, String id, 
                    double gpa, int year)
    {
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.id = id;
        this.gpa = gpa;
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return this.lastName + ", " + this.firstName + ": " + this.id + " "
               + this.gpa + " " + this.year;
    }

    public double getGPA()
    {
        return gpa;
    }

    public boolean isBetter (Student s)
    {
        return (this.gpa > ((Student)s).getGPA());
    }

    public boolean isHonors()
    {
        if (this.gpa >= 3.5)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

CS152 class -

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class CS152
{
    public static final int MAXSIZE = 22;
    private static int size = 0;

    public static Student[] createList (Scanner scan) throws IOException
    {       
        Student[] list = new Student [MAXSIZE];
        return populateList (list, scan);
    }

    private static Student[] populateList (Student[] list, Scanner scan)
    {
        Student s;
        if (size < MAXSIZE && scan.hasNext())
        {
            s = new Student (scan.next(), scan.next(), scan.next(),
                             scan.nextDouble(), scan.nextInt());
            list[size] = s;
            size++;
            System.out.println (s);
            return populateList (list, scan);
        }
        else
        {
            return list;
        }
    }

    public static int getSize()
    {
        return size;
    }

    // Returns String of all students. Variable n is actual size of the list.
    // Assume that n is positive. Recursive code.
    public static String toString (Student[] list, int n)
    {
        String s = " ";
        if (n == 1)
        {
            return s += list[0];
        }
        else
        {
            s += list[n].toString() + "\n";
            s += "\n";
        }
        return s + toString (list, n - 1);
    }

    // Returns the best student. Must use method isBetter in the code.
    // Variable n is actual size of the list. Assume that n is positive.
    public static Student findBestStudent (Student[] list, int n)
    {
        if (n == 1)
        {
            return list[0];
        }
        else if (list[n].isBetter (list[n - 1]))
        {
            return list[n];
        }
        else
        {
            return findBestStudent (list, n - 1);
        }        
    }

    // Returns the number of honor students in the list.
    // Must call the method isHonors(). Variable n is actual size of the list.
    // Assume that n is positive.
    public static int countHonors (Student[] list, int n)
    {
        if (n == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else if (list[n].isHonors())
        {
            return 1 + countHonors (list, n - 1);
        }
        else
        {
            return countHonors (list, n - 1);
        }
    }

    static ArrayList<Student> studentsList = new ArrayList<Student>();
    public static ArrayList <Student> honorsStuds (Student[] list, int n)
    {
        if (n == 0)
        {
            return studentsList;
        }
        else
        {
            boolean currentIsHonors = list[n - 1].isHonors();
            if (currentIsHonors)
            {
                studentsList.add(list[n - 1]);
                return honorsStuds (list, n - 1);
            }
            else
            {
                return honorsStuds (list, n - 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

TestStudents class -

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class TestStudents
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        File input = new File ("input.txt");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (input);
        Student[] studentArray = CS152.createList (scan);
    }
}
```

I incorporated the FileWriter into the TestStudents class. A list of all students is now displayed. I am still having difficulties trying to call the methods findBestStudent, countHonors, and honorsStuds and implementing them into TestStudents. Here is the revised TestStudents class:

TestStudents class -

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class TestStudents
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        File input = new File ("input.txt");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (input);
        System.out.println ("All students: ");
        Student[] studentArray = CS152.createList (scan);


        File output = new File ("output.txt");
        FileWriter fWriter = new FileWriter (output);
        PrintWriter pWriter = new PrintWriter (fWriter);
        pWriter.println (input);
        pWriter.close();    
    }
}
```

Comment: `static Student[] populateList (Student[] list, Scanner scan)` is being called recursively - one level per student read - for absolutely no reason.  You don't want `if ( /* not done */ ) { /* ... */  populateList( ) }`, you just want a `while( /* not done */) { ... }` loop.

Comment: You've already written the code to find the best student, etc.  You just need to call the functions and print out the result.

Comment: That is part that I am having trouble with. I printed out all of the students. I now have to print out the methods findBestStudent, countHonors, and honorsStuds. Unfortunately, I am not able to get them to print in the output.txt file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To write to a file, you need a [FileWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html).

Using a FileWriter and [Try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), usage would look something like this:

```java
try(FileWriter w = new FileWriter(new File("output.txt"))) {
    w.append("Some string");
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Output.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

If you don't use a try-with-resources, make sure to `close()` the `Writer` to make sure resources do not leak. In fact, you should also make sure to close your `Scanner` as well, as leaving it un-closed will leak resources.

In the future, [ask one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222735).

To access your Students, you just need to read them from the array.

```java
System.out.println(studentArray[0].getGPA()); // prints the GPA of the first student
for (int i=0; i<CS152.getSize(); i++) {
    System.out.println(studentArray[i]); // prints every Student
}
```

[[Note that this design of having a long array with `null` elements at the end with `CS152.class` telling you how many are filled is bad design. I would have the read procedure return a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html)`<Student>`, which manages its own length. Given the name of the class is `CS152`, however, this is probably either given to you by the teacher of CS-152 or done previously, so I'll work with what you have.]]

Comment: I incorporated the FileWriter into the TestStudents class. A list of all students is now displayed. I am still having difficulties trying to call the methods findBestStudent, countHonors, and honorsStuds and implementing them into TestStudents.

Comment: Yes, the methods public static Student[] createList (Scanner scan) and private static Student[] populateList (Student[] list, Scanner scan) where already given and populated. The code that you posted that reads the students from the array does work. I had it already retrieving the list from input.txt. The only part that I cannot seem to call are the methods that I previously mentioned, while incorporating them into output.txt. I have used input.txt in a previous program. However transferring the methods into output.txt in new to me.